# Angular formdata with object data

Tags: angular, laravel, multipartform-data

Good morning,

I'm developing an application in Angular V1(I know I need to update the application to the Version 4 of Angular) with Laravel.

I want to create an object with multiple products and save it on database. Each product has an id, a description, a link to the website of product, (others fields) and finally an image to upload.

To do this I did a research and found the FormData although I need to append each key to the formData. (Maybe this isn't the best practice).
I don't know If I explain my problem well, but this is my code. (I'm using lodash library).

```
var requestProducts = new FormData();
_.each(vm.products, function(product){
  _.each(product, function(key, item)){
      requestProducts.append(key, item);
  }
}   
});
```

How do I send an object with an image to upload the image to the server and save the rest of information in database?